# Dual Boot, Cannot open Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, secure-boot

I was able to successfully install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my HPPavilion laptop with Windows10 as the main OS.
After Ubuntu installation, it asked to restart. After restart I do not get Grub menu, and it starts Windows OS. I tried disable secure boot, and lots of other things.

Note: I cannot access Ubuntu, so cannot access Terminal for commands.

I found https://www.supergrubdisk.org/
should I use this? or is there any other option?

Comment: There is a direct command : 
`bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` 
to show grub menu on boot. 

The steps are:

 1) - Boot into Windows OS
  2) -  Combine Windows + r together and type cmd to open command prompt.
  3) - Type `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` 
and hit enter 

Once done you will start getting GRUB menu on boot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried the command, I also found out that I can use live ubuntu usb, by trying ubuntu and then using Terminal. There, I tried bunch of ommands to fix grub, it ran successfully but no avail. als, mentioning, programs like Easybcd 23 wont work because my HP laptop BIOS mode is UEFI and not legacy. Cannot change it so far from what I found.Have tried all option is BIOS startup nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem, this boot-repair software helped me.
Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

Here is the link  [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I am yet to try this. but if successful il post. So, far fixing it through internal commands does not work